# Need Zyxel Speedlink router to communicate with Cisco 886VA router

Tags: cisco-commands

I'm trying to connect a Zyxel Speedlink router to a Cisco 886VA.

The problem is that the FE ports on the Cisco 886VA are switchports and I can't assign the ports an IP address directly. Therefore, I have to create a SVI and add the FE interface to the VLAN.

For example, if I assign the switchport interface FE0 on the 886VA to VLAN 1(native) and give the SVI an IP address of 192.168.1.1/24, I can't ping the Zyxel IP address 192.168.1.2/24.

I believe this is because the Zyxel isn't compatible with Cisco VLANs, but I'm not sure.

Could someone please let me know if it's possible for the Zyxel Speedlink to talk to Cisco 886VA?

Comment: It should work.  Verify that the VLAN interface is up, and the port is up.

Comment: The VLAN interface was definitely up and the port was up. I'm wondering if the problem is that the Zyxel doesn't recognize Cisco's vlans

Comment: I agree that it should work.

Comment: Any more thoughts?

Comment: Since you're using the native VLAN, there is no VLAN information in the ethernet packet.  So it's standard 802.3 Ethernet.  Are you sure the Zytel is working?  If you connect it to a PC, will it ping?   Have you replaced the cable?

Comment: may you provide your configuration

Comment: The Zyxel is definitely working ... its connected to our ISP,  so yes it will ping. We have replaced the cable. Don't forget, I'm not able to configure an ip address directly on the interface. So, what we're doing here is trying to connect a layer2 switchport (cisco) to a Layer3 port (Zyxel). Is that the problem?

Comment: @cpatte7372 did any answer help you? Or did you find out what the problem was? Please consider accepting an answer or create one yourself and accept that, so that your question does not pop up forever. :-)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Zyxel will probably not respond to ping because it has its firewall enabled, and it purposely ignores any attempt to connect from the WAN side.

You should be able to connect the Zyxel to a switch port on the Cisco router. You have a couple of options there. You can use DHCP on the Cisco to assign the IP address to the Zyxel, or you can statically assign an IP address to the Zyxel. In either case, you want to connect the Zyxel WAN port to the Cisco switch port. Statically configuring the Zyxel means manually configuring everything that it would expect to get from an ISP (e.g. DNS).

Another option is to set the Zyxel to bridge mode and allow the Cisco to be the router, and the Zyxel to be only a Wi-Fi AP. The Cisco would need to handle the DHCP functions.

The Zyxel is a consumer-grade device, and questions about configuring those are specifically off-topic. You can ask those questions on Super User.

Comment: But its not possible to configure and IP address on a layer 2 switchport. And if you configure a SVI it will be configured on a Vlan and I don't think the Zyxel supports Cisco vlan tagging.

Comment: VLAN tagging is only on trunk ports. The access port to which you connect the Zyxel won't have tags.

Comment: Like Ron M said, make sure you have "switchport mode access" configured on the Cisco, not "switchport mode trunk". If you do this, then it really does not matter what Vlan ID you use: it does not have to be 1. Obviously, though, the SVI id has to match the Vlan ID that you use.